# Failed on converting a decimal number to a hexadecimal string in Java

Tags: java, string, int, hex, decimal

I'm a novice Java learner and I follow Introduction to Java Programming by D. Liang page by page.

Anyway, I've written a program that converts any given decimal number to a hexadecimal string (in theory at least). I leave the code below. My problem is, the code works occasionally. I.e., it works for number 127 but it does not for number 221. I wonder why does it do so.

P.S. I'm aware that there's an another very useful method for this operation but i would like to know why my solution does not work. It's important for me because i want to be a good programmer who knows what he does.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Create a Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Prompt user to enter any decimal number
    System.out.println("Enter a decimal number, please: ");
    int decNum = input.nextInt();

    int division = decNum;
    String allDigits = "";

    //Calculate the digitZero
    allDigits += setDigit(division);
    //Calculate the other digits
    do{
        division = division / 16;
        allDigits+=setDigit(division);
    } while (division >= 16);

    //Reverse the string into a normal hexadecimal view
    allDigits = new StringBuilder(allDigits).reverse().toString();
    //Display the result
    System.out.println("" + allDigits);
}

public static String setDigit(int Number) {
    int division = Number;
    int digit = division % 16;
    String hexDigits = "";
    if (digit > 9) {
        switch (digit) {
            case 10:
                hexDigits += "A";
            case 11:
                hexDigits += "B";
            case 12:
                hexDigits += "C";
            case 13:
                hexDigits += "D";
            case 14:
                hexDigits += "E";
            case 15:
                hexDigits += "F";
        }
    } else {
        hexDigits += Integer.toString(digit);
    }
    return hexDigits;
}
```

Comment: You have an example which doesn't work, so the best way to understand why is to step through the code in your debugger to see which lines don't do what you expected. In particular, I would try `10` to hexidecimal, you might get a shock. ;)

Comment: Once you get this working I suggest trying to cut the lines in half, and then in half again.

Comment: Also try writing it without using `+` or `+=` for String as this is a performance hit.

Comment: Tip: take a look on switch-case statement and when to use "break" (I just do not want to write answer, let you read about it and fix yourself).

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me notice that mighty command :) I can't believe how did I forget it. I am a bit ashamed for asking this question, too. @PeterLawrey I was struggling with using debugging but finally, I've managed to learn it. Btw, I didnt know that using a `+` or `+=` decreases the performance. I couldnt help myself but using a full string of hexadecimal digits and grabbing them by charAt method in order to overcome this trick. Thank you for your interest and help guys

Comment: @TossTheAtoms think about what you could do with `stringBuilder.append ("0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(number % 16));`

Comment: I lookeded over for what is stringBuilder and found that it's a seperate class that needs to be defined exclusively. Forums i've encountered says that it's better to use stringBuilder.append since ordinary `string1+=string2` allocates the memory again and again each time in a loop. I got it. But, my code's final form is like this: http://imgur.com/LC9PWLz (sorry i couldn't manage to post it here in correct form) and I don't see any difference between my code or going with stringBuilder. Thats my humble opinion of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget about `break;` in the end of every case statement.
From [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) :

> If one of the case constants is equal to the value of the expression, then we say that the case matches, and all statements after the matching case label in the switch block, if any, are executed in sequence.

Try to replace your `switch` block with:

```
    switch (digit) {
        case 10:
            hexDigits += "A";
            break;
        case 11:
            hexDigits += "B";
            break;
        case 12:
            hexDigits += "C";
            break;
        case 13:
            hexDigits += "D";
            break;
        case 14:
            hexDigits += "E";
            break;
        case 15:
            hexDigits += "F";
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't believe myself that this was my problem. I'm sorry for that :) Thanks very much